# Express 4 Multer / req.body and res.json not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm trying to do a single image file + text fields upload with using Express 4.0 & multer 1.1.0. The image file itself correctly uploads to the right destination but I'm getting errors with the text field and response:

> 1) multer's req.body req.file objects are undefined if logged in console
>
> 2) res.json (and also res.send when tested) gets the error - TypeError: res.json is not a function at Object.handle)

multer is configured as follows using moment.js for dates, which is almost line-for-line from the multer Github documentation:

```
//standard express-generator server.js requires
//passport.js implementation

var multer   = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb){
    cb(null, './public/photoUploads/' + moment().year() + moment().month());
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb){
    cb(null, req.user._id + moment().unix());
  }
})

var upload = multer({storage:storage});

require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport); //passport login routes - will eventually move app.post into this file

app.post('/upload/photoData', upload.array('photo'), function(err, req, res) {

   var title = req.body.title;
   var description = req.body.description;
   var photoURL = req.file.filename;

   var jsonResponse = {
     "title": title,
     "description": description,
     "photoURL": photoURL
   }

   console.log(jsonResponse);
   res.json(jsonResponse);
});
```

And here is the client-side form

```
 <form id="photo-data" method="post" action="/upload/photoData" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="modal-body">

                <label for="image" class="control-label">Photo upload</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="photo" id="photo-main">

                <label for="caption" class="control-label">Title:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="photo-title">

                <label for="long-text" class="control-label">Further description:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="message-text">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button id="submit-photo" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>                   
            </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature for error handlers in Express is `(err, req, res, next)` (4 parameters), but Express sees less 4 than parameters in your handler so it assumes you're adding a normal route handler. The problem is that the order of your route handler parameters is wrong, it should just be `(req, res)`. That will fix your `res.json()` error.

For your file field, you're currently telling `multer` you're expecting multiple files, so in that case you will need to check `req.files` instead of `req.file`. If you used `upload.single('photo')` instead, you could use `req.file`.

As for the non-file fields, make sure they are in fact submitted to the server by checking the network request for the form submission with your browser's developer tools.

Comment: I should add that if the destination is defined as a function, it is necessary to make sure that this directory exists and if not, create it yourself.

Comment: Thanks! It works now. Fixing the req.file issue seems to have also fixed the req.body without further work - maybe the 2 are linked.